# A book written before 1960 about teens searching for pirate treasure using an invention that listens to the past

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This book was bound in yellow hardcover, and concerned the invention of a 'time radio' that could hear whatever sounds happened at any location in the past.  You had to physically take the 'radio' to the location you wanted to hear.  Teens used it to listen to pirates discussing their treasure and where to hide it.  Eventually the teens were able to narrow down the hiding place to a hidden cove and dig up the treasure.  It was not a Danny Dunn novel.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.